# Multiply and sum numpy arrays with shapes (x,y,z) and (x,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, linear-algebra

So I have a 3D data-set (x,y,z), and i want to sum over one of the axes (x) with a set of weights, w = w(x). The start and end index i am summing over is different for every (y,z), I have solved this by masking the 3D-array. The weights are constant with regard to the two variables i am not summing over. Both answers regarding implementation and mathematics are appreciated (is there a smart linalg. way of doing this?).

I have a 3D masked array (A) of shape (x,y,z) and a 1D array (t) of shape (x,). Is there a good way to multiply every (y,z) element in A with the corresponding number in t without expanding t to a 3D array? My current solution is using np.tensordot to make a 3D array of the same shape as A, that holds all the t-values, but it feels very unsatisfactory to spend runtime building the "new_t" array, which is essensially just y*z copies of t.

Example of current solution:

```
a1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
               [5,6,7,8],
               [9,10,11,12]])

a2 = np.array([[0,1,2,3],
               [4,5,6,7],
               [8,9,10,11]])

#note: A is a masked array, mask is a 3D array of bools
A = np.ma.masked_array([a1,a2],mask)
t = np.array([10,11])

new_t = np.tensordot(t, np.ones(A[0].shape), axes = 0)
return np.sum(A*new_t, axis=0)
```

In essence i want to perform t*A[:,i,j] for all i,j with the shortest possible runtime, preferably without using too many other libraries than numpy and scipy.

Another way of producing desired output (again, with far too high run time):

```
B = [[t*A[:,i,j] for j in range(A.shape[2])] for i in range(A.shape[1])]
return np.sum(B,axis=2)
```

Comment: Something like `np.einsum('ijk,i->jk', A, t)`?

Comment: Thanks! Edited now, A is a masked array, and it looks like einsum doesn't care about the masks. Still looking at it, einsum seems like a good way to go.

Comment: Even just `tensordot` might work, with the right broadcasting tricks. That's usually just some trial end error with dummy data... which is why I am too lazy to do it and write an answer :)

Comment: I have trial and errored for quite a few hours before posting, which is why i was wondering if there was a better way. Einsum workes like a charm, except it uses the masked values.

Comment: If it's a masked array, show that in the example, not just in a footnote.  As a general rule, non-ma functions do not pay attention to the mask.  The mask is used only if the function delegates the action the array's method.

Comment: With `einsum` and `matmul` (`@`), `tensordot` isn't that useful anymore.  Basically `tensordot` reshapes and transposes the inputs to produce `np.dot` compatible arrays.  Then it converts the result back with more reshape and transpose.

Comment: That probably explains why tensordot was slower than einsum, ... and why I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set up my input-output with high dimention arrays and tensordot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for good answers! Using tensordot like @alyhosny proposed worked, but replacing masked values with zeros using

```
A = np.ma.MaskedArray.filled(A,0)
```

before summing with einsum (thanks @phipsgabler) gave half the run time. Final code:

```
A = np.ma.MaskedArray(A,mask)
A = np.ma.MaskedArray.filled(A,0)
return np.einsum('ijk,i->jk',A,t)
```

Answer (score 1):

inspired by @phipsgabler  comment

```
arr1 = np.tensordot(A.T,t,axes=1).T
arr1
array([[ 10,  31,  52,  73],
       [ 94, 115, 136, 157],
       [178, 199, 220, 241]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, i guess i have a lot to learn about using tensordot (and other np linalg functions) :) but i figured i could just fill the masked array with zeros in place of masks before summing, and that gave right below half the runtime :)